# Finding Expression Blend Designers

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

What are some recommendations for finding Expression Blend/WPF Designers to perform contract work?  I think a (local) freelance designer might be the most reasonably priced, but I don't even know where to start.

As additional background, I am located in the Midwest region of the US, where designers are not as prevalent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might discover it is extremely difficult to find these people right now ... as most designers are familiar with the Adobe suite of products and not the Expression suite.

I think a lot of people are learning that these skills need to be cultivated ... whether a software developer with designer tendencies moves more toward the designer side ... or whether a designer with developer tendencies moves more toward the developer side. I am an example of the former.

I would also add that cultivating these skills is much harder when that person is not working in close proximity (as most freelancers work off-site or even far away).

All that being said, I am sure everyone would love to hear if you have success in locating people with these skills ... and where you found them.

You might find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624/designers-and-developers-working-together) interesting too.

Answer (score 2):

Craigslist is great, especially if you will work with someone remotely. I'm also a big fan of LinkedIn.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I agree that the role of Expression Blend 'Integrators'is hard to find. Check out the [site](http://projectrosetta.com/) , which is an intiative to boost the design world http://projectrosetta.com/